# In J, what does the suffix "__" do?

Tags: j

I'm maintaining a large code base in J, and a few rare functions and variables end with `__` (two underscores).

Normally, `__` is used to reference something in a locale.

```
barObj =: conew 'Bar'
Foo__barObj
```

However, I have this:

```
Foo__
```

Declared as:

```
Foo__=: 3 : 0
```

Is that another syntax for a static function? Is it accessible to all locales?

EDIT:

From what I can gather, it's not local. A variable declared thus:

```
FooVar__ =.
```

can be referenced by another function, despite `=.` making it seem local. The same way any "into locale" declarations are always "global to the locale" (`Foo__Bar =.` and `Foo__Bar =:` are the same).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ending with double-underscore is an old technique for referencing a name in the base locale. Here are details from [the relevant part of the Locale lab](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Studio/Locales#base):

> A locative with no locale name between the bracketing `_` characters is
>   treated as if it had the name base.
>
> `abc__` is the same as `abc_base_`
>
> Treating `__` as `_base_` is for compatibility with earlier versions, and
>   in general you should use `_base_` .

Comment: Thanks kaleidic! I've also got another question that should be easy for you to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905439/chain-verbs-in-j